# Bigquery - how to aggregate data based on conditions

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, data-analysis, aggregation

I have a simple table like the following, which has product, price, cost and category. price and cost can be null.

[image]

And this table is being updated from time to time. Now I want to have a daily summary of the table content grouped by category, to see in each category, how many products that has no price, and how many has a price, and how many products has a price that is higher than the cost, so the result table would look like the following:

[image]

I think I can get a query running everyday by setting up query re-run schedule in bigQuery, so I can have three rows of data appended to the result table everyday.

But the problem is, how can I get those three rows? I know I can group by, but how do I get the count with those conditions like not null, larger than, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want window functions:

```
select t.*
       countif(price is nuill) over (partition by date) as products_no_price,
       countif(price <= cost) over (partition by date) as products_price_lower_than_cost
from t;
```

You can run this code on the table that has `date` column.  In fact, you don't need to store the last two columns.

If you want to insert the first table into the second, then there is no date and you can simply use:

```
select t.*
       countif(price is nuill) over () as products_no_price,
       countif(price <= cost) over () as products_price_lower_than_cost
from t;
```

Comment: Big Thanks! Countif is what I need!